# SwiftUI not updating property change on a @State variable

Tags: swift, swiftui, observedobject

I have a swiftui application with a model structure similar to below. `Event` and `Media` are classes managed by a data manager and they're passed in to a parent-view `EventsListView` that shows events with a media count and tapping on event will take you details `EventDetailsView` where it shows all media belonging to an event.

`EventsListView` takes on an `Event` object from data manager and creates a `@State` object of type `EventDisplayModel` based on it's properties that is used to display thumbnail and count of media in it.

`EventDetailsView` takes on same `Event` and displayed each `Media`. It keeps reference to `Event` as an `@ObservedObject`. The details view can enable or disable media that belongs to an event.

The problem I'm having is, when user enable or disable their media from `EventDetailsView` they're correctly captured in both details view as well as changed properly at data manager level. The parent view `EventsListView` however is not being updated of these changes when the user goes back. I can see the view body changes in events list screen but the count of media still remains original value, despite the actual `Event` carries the updated values. The @State property is also getting changed, but UI doesnt get updated. Why does this happen?

```swift
// UI model

struct EventDisplayModel: Identifiable {
    init(from event: Event) {
        self.id = event.id; self.thumbnailId = event.thumbnailId; self.title = event.name; self.count = event.selectedMediaCount
    }
    
    let id: UUID
    var thumbnailId: String?
    var title: String
    var count: Int
}

// Data manager models

class Event: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var thumbnailId: String?
    @Published var media: [Media] = []
    @Published var name: String = ""
    
    var selectedMediaCount: Int {
        media.filter { $0.isSelected }.count
    }
}

class Media: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    internal init(thumbnailId: String? = nil, isSelected: Bool = false) {
        self.thumbnailId = thumbnailId
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }
    
    let id = UUID()
    var thumbnailId: String?
    
    @Published var isSelected: Bool = false
}
```

How the `EventsListView's` cell view is constructed

```swift
struct EvenListCell: View {

  @State private var displayModel: EventDisplayModel

  var body: some View {
    Text("count: \(displayModel.count)")  // doesn't get updated
  }

  init(model: Event) {
    _displayModel = State(initialValue: .init(from: model))
  }
}
```

How the `EventDetailView` each media item is rendered and the enabled state gets updated.

```swift
struct EventDetailsCell: View {
    @ObservedObject var mediaItem: Media

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // UI Logic
        }
        .onTapGesture {
          // This gets updated in Event details page as well as on original model owned by data manager. But the changes are not reflected by EventList
            mediaItem.isSelected.toggle() 
        }
    }
}
```

Puzzled by how the model changes are not reflected in the `EventsList` screen. Should I discard the `EventDisplayModel` all together and keep individual @State variables where needed with a reference to the `Event` model as `@ObservedObject` (These state properties will become really complex however with future planned feature updates)

Comment: You seem to have things back to front. The `class Event: ObservableObject`
 is the model that need to be `observed` by the view, that is, 
 needs to be declared in the view hierarchy,
 such as `@StateObject var event = Event(...)`.

Look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)
 
 just follow the examples.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So the `Media` is held as a @StateObject by last child view. The only difference I'm doing at parent level is, instead of holding on to the `Event` object, I create a @State variable with `Event` itself. The reason for that is the parent's view logic will get complicated and wanted to separate it from actual `Event`'s raw properties. 

But anyway I will refactor it to hold on a Event itself and keep separate @state properties relevant to individual fields for now and see if it works.

Comment: Note also, nesting `ObservableObject` like you have `[Media]` inside your `Event`,
 is a well known source of problems. If you are targeting ios17+,
 I suggest you use the new more advanced observation framework, [Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)

Comment: Thanks, we have to support iOS16 as well at this stage.

Comment: Change all your classes to struct and review the Apple SwiftUI tutorials. There is no reason why State would update.

Answer (score 0):

`Event` should be a struct because `Identifiable` by `id` doesn't make sense for a class that already is an object reference.

`View` structs should not have an `init` because it will break the View struct's change detection if you do any transformation of the params in `init` vs transforming on the down e.g. in via computed properties in parent `View`.

Comment: I'm refactoring the view's init part to get rid of it. The `id` of the model `Event` comes from elsewhere through network and local db. I've only included in this example to mention there is an `id` property attached for it. (When used in swiftui lists and other filtering operations etc..)